# Docker openedx make dev.provision fails

Tags: docker, provisioning, devstack, openedx

I was trying to deploy the docker based devstack on my local machine. I followed the official installation guide found here: https://github.com/edx/devstack. I went through most of the processes without a glitch until I had to run  `make dev.provision`

when i run the provisioning command I encounter the following failed task

```
TASK [server_utils : Install ubuntu system packages] ***************************
    failed: [localhost] (item=[u'ack-grep', u'mosh', u'tree', u'screen', u'tmux', u'curl', u'vim', u'dnsutils', u'inetutils-telnet', u'netcat']) => {"failed": true, "item": ["ack-grep", "mosh", "tree", "screen", "tmux", "curl", "vim", "dnsutils", "inetutils-telnet", "netcat"], "msg": "Failed to update apt cache."}
    to retry, use: --l/admin/theming/sitetheme/imit @/edx/app/edx_ansible/edx_ansible/playbooks/edxapp.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I accessed the lms container through bash using `docker exec -it mycontainer bash` and ran `apt update` manually because it seemed that the provisioner encountered an error when it was trying to "Install ubuntu system packages" and subsequently "Failed to update apt cache." the apt update command output was the following:

```
# apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease            
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                
Hit:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease              
Ign:6 http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Hit:7 http://ppa.edx.org xenial InRelease                                      
Err:8 http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu xenial Release                   
  Connection failed [IP: 206.251.255.63 80]
Reading package lists... Done                
E: The repository 'http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

What do I need to do to fix this error? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try to comment out `#http://nginx.org/packages/ubuntu xenial Release ` in /etc/apt/sources.list file or some files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d folder.

Comment: Aren't those updates needed though?

Comment: its nginx so I think its not involve in this docker.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a similar error in Fedora when running `make dev.provision`. It was caused because my docker version was the old one (when I ran `docker version` i got 1.13.1) and openedx required Docker CE, which is the new version of docker.

To solve the issue I uninstalled my docker version and installed Docker CE as described [here](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/fedora/) and the command worked fine.

Comment: My docker version is the latest (Docker CE 18.06, api version 1.38)